# Hi how does one develop a libre offic calc extension in python

Tags: python, api, libreoffice-calc

Hi  am developing a libre office calc coingecko api extension that gets data from the public coin gecko api and returns prices of specific currencies. I already have the python script figured out what I can't get is how to go about creating an extension. I have tried all the sdk documentation and all I find are redirecting links. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unzip an existing extension that uses python-UNO for Calc, such as this project I'm involved with: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/lingtools.